# Audio missing on new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS laptop

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, laptop, soundcard

New notebook come with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS preinstalled, and audio is missing, no sound. **MUTE** is off. How many efforts is required to enable such basic functionality on new laptop? I'm have no much willingness to install a bunch of various drivers on new laptop in order to provide an elementary functionality that available out of the box on any notebook with win OS. The video playback of flash videos was misssed too, I managed to solve this by installing adobe flash plugin. Audio devices:

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 0b)
Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Sound settings:
[Sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK4eg.png)

sudo aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Try opening Alsamixer in a terminal to make sure that it's not muted. As for flash, Ubuntu has never included proprietary software "out of the box". It has always had to be installed by the user.

Comment: `Alsamixer v1.0.25`, `Card: HDA Intel` , `Chip: Generic 0000 ID 0`,
`This sound device does not have any contols.`

Comment: Post the output of `sudo aplay -l`

Comment: Added output to the top of topic.

Comment: I don't have any definite answers. Lots of people were having issues with sound in 12.04 because PulseAudio was still pretty new. I'm going to suggest `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`. Hopefully that will get you the controls that you were told you don't have.

Comment: Here is alsa-info.sh script [output](http://pastebin.com/raw/g8TQyUjz) that can give some more information.

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/default/speech-dispatcher` and make sure `Run=no`. If all's well there but still no sound, try: `sudo alsa force-reload`. If that doesn't work, then try: `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio` followed by `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`, and again do `sudo alsa force-reload`.

Comment: The sound coming from the headphones (I just didn't tested this before).

Comment: In that case, the issue may be with your speakers instead of with the software.

Comment: No, speakers worked before. After applying last commands (re-install alsa-base & pulseaudio) "Speaker testing for analog output" not works anymore, although it worked before via headphones attached, also missing the speaker icon which is normally located above.

Comment: Where to get latest `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms` **.deb** file?

Comment: https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages

Comment: You might consider upgrading to a more recent release. A newer kernel might solve your issue.

Comment: You can always test later releases using a live usb if you don't want to overwrite the current installation.

Comment: Is it possible upgrade to 14.04 from Guest session? I can no login from administrator account anymore.